# Talend - How to execute multiple statement along with prepare statement in tMySQLInput

Tags: mysql, etl, talend

I am new to Talend. I tried to run multiple select statements as **MSSQL Query 1** to retrieve maximum Id's in different tables using tMSSQLInput component. It worked fine.

**MSSQL Query 1** "DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT(SELECT max(Id) FROM table1) AS maxIdAC,
(SELECT max(Id) FROM table2' + CAST((YEAR(GETDATE())-1) as varchar(10)) +')
AS maxIdACT, (SELECT max(Id) FROM table3) AS maxIdAF'
EXEC (@sqlCommand)"
I tried to achieve the same logic with **MSSQL Query 2** using tMySQLInput Component. It throws the **ERROR**. When I run the same query in MySQL Server console. It works fine without any error.

**MSSQL Query 2** "set @multiplequery = concat('select (', concat('select Max(Id) FROM table1',CAST(YEAR(CURDATE())-1 as CHAR(50))),')AS maxIdACT,(' , 'select max(Id) FROM table2',') AS maxIdAC,(' , 'select max(Id) FROM table3',') AS maxIdAF');
prepare execQuery FROM @multiplequery;
execute execQuery"

**Error** Exception in component tDBInput_1 (ExtAndStoreData)
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'prepare execQuery FROM @multiplequery;
execute execQuery' at line 2

Could someone tell me how to achieve this in Talend. I also read that it is possible using tMysqlRow component. But I could not figure out how to run the above-mentioned **MSSQL Query 2** using tMySqlRow Component. Could someone help

Comment: Yes, your task could  easily be done using  tMysqlRow  you wil have to separate your query using different tMysqlRow   linked by onComponent Ok

Comment: @AmineBenKhelifa: Thanks for your reply. Could you please tell me how i need to seperate query to achieve this using tMySQLRow.